# How to project nodes created by relative position on curve to axis and below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

In case I have two curves created with [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) I can draw a line between two **relatively** positioned nodes on each. In this example there is an arrow between the points at 50% of each curve.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]

\addplot[color=black,mark=square*] table {
x y 
1 1 
2 2
3 3
} 
node [pos=0.5,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (A) {};

\addplot[color=black,mark=square*] table {
x y 
1 2 
2 3
} 
;

\addplot[color=black,mark=square*] table {
x y 
2 1 
3 2
} 
node [pos=0.5,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (B) {};

\draw[latex-latex] (A) -- (B);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**But how can I set just one node and get a second and third one projected on each axis?**

**And how to get a node outside the axis relatively to the one set on the curve?**

So basically I'm looking for the **red nodes** in the following picture and like to draw the **red lines** and **green lines**?

[image]

Any help? There are questions around which could solve my problem, but they all aim at different things and I miss the essential parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rel axis cs` inside the `axis` to draw the green lines and set named coordinates at the projected points.

```
\draw[green,very thick]
  (A|-{rel axis cs:0,0})coordinate(Ax)--(A)--({rel axis cs:0,0}|-A)coordinate(Ay);
```

Then you can draw the red nodes and lines outside the `axis`.

```
\draw[red,very thick]
  (Ax)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}--+(0,-5mm)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}
  (Ay)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}--+(-5mm,0)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=black,mark=square*] table {
  x y 
  1 1 
  2 2
  3 3
  } 
  node [pos=0.5,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (A) {};
\addplot[color=black,mark=square*] table {
  x y 
  1 2 
  2 3
  } 
  ;
\addplot[color=black,mark=square*] table {
  x y 
  2 1 
  3 2
  } 
  node [pos=0.5,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (B) {};
\draw[latex-latex] (A) -- (B);
\draw[green,very thick]
  (A|-{rel axis cs:0,0})coordinate(Ax)--(A)--({rel axis cs:0,0}|-A)coordinate(Ay);
\end{axis}
\draw[red,very thick]
  (Ax)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}--+(0,-5mm)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}
  (Ay)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}--+(-5mm,0)node{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```